# How do I prevent health check requests from storing unwanted sessions in my database?

Tags: node.js, session, http-headers, google-cloud-platform, express-session

We have a Node.js app running in the flexible environment on Google Cloud Platform. This app uses express-session in combination with connect-mongodb-session to create and save sessions to keep track of clients. The problem, however, is that it also seems to create millions of sessions because the app does not yet discriminate between "regular" requests and health check requests. Health checks are requests done very frequently - sometimes multiple times per second - by Google Cloud Platform to test whether the app is still running. If not, GCP restarts the app.

I do not think it is desirable to create a new - or any - session for each new health check request. Is there a way to make some adjustments to the code to make an exception for these health checks? There does not seem to be much discussion on this topic yet. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places. So I would like some advice.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) is unique to the health check traffic; you can filter by that, avoiding the creation of a session as desired.